# Is there a way to make an overlay with an arrow AND border like google?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am working on my code to create a green circle with your name on it with an arrow and border just like the one that google use.

please find the sample image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckB3G.png]

I have already created a green circle and a name using css and html which you can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dazoq0yx/).

```
<div class="profileImage">
  <span id="profilename" class="profilename"></span>
  <div class="flex-container">
  </div> 
</div>
```

```css
.profileImage {
    -webkit-background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 18px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.profilename {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstName = 'Robert';
  var lastName = 'Jones';
  var intials = firstName.charAt(0)+""+lastName.charAt(0);
  document.getElementById("profilename").innerHTML = intials;
});
```

When I click on a green circle, I want to display the overlay with a border but I have got no idea how to do this. I tried to find it on google but I couldn't find it.

Can you please show me an example how I can display the overlay with a grey border that come with my first name, last name, email address and a signout button?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "flexbox"? Do you mean the larger overlay with detailed content? `flexbox` is a CSS layout technique which is likely confusing people.

Comment: @BryceHowitson yes sorry about that, I thought the flexbox is the border that come with the top arrow like the google avater. So how I could make the larger overlay with detailed content like the google avater?

Comment: Is the problem the arrow? Otherwise its just a div with `border: 1px solid #ddd`

Comment: look into [CSS triangles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). You'll need to stack two (one for the foreground color and one for the "border"). I have to leave for a while but will provide an example if there aren't other answers by the time I'm back online.

Comment: @BryceHowitson I want the arrow that come with the border, image, span texts for full name and email, 2 buttons.

Comment: Well stick with one problem at a time 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll get you started with an overlay that includes an arrow with a border around the whole thing.

Basically, you're doing a bit of "visual miss direction". We used CSS borders to generate a triangle of the **SAME** color as the box background. This gets positioned its (height - border width) above the box. This puts the triangle **OVER** the top of the border, effectively hiding it.

Then there's a second triangle with a color that matches the border of the box. We position this triangle BEHIND the first triangle (using `z-index`) and offset the second triangle the border width from the first. This makes for a "fake" border because only the border width of the second triangle shows.

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 
 // styling
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.arrow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
 top: -9px;
 right: 10px;
 
}
.arrow:after {
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent;
 left:-10px;
 top:-1px;
 z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
 <div class="arrow"></div>
 <div class="overlayContent">

 </div>
</div>
```

We used two elements (arrow and content) inside the overlay wrapper because we're rounding the corners using `overflow:hidden` this would cause our arrows to be cut off as well. So instead we'll have an extra container. The content area uses `flexbox` to push the button bar to the bottom regardless of the size. There are other ways to do this but this is easy.

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 
 // styling
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 4px;
}

.arrow {
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
 top: -9px;
 right: 10px;
 
}
.arrow:after {
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #ccc transparent;
 left:-10px;
 top:-1px;
 z-index:-1;
}

.overlayContent {
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-radius: 4px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.top {
 flex-basis: 70%;
}
.bottom {
 flex-basis: 30%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
 <div class="arrow"></div>
 <div class="overlayContent">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

That's the fundamentals of the overlay. Try filling in the content you want and ask more questions if you need help.

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is what I am looking for.